# How to get Firefox to run video in HTML5

Tags: html, firefox, video

I'm using HTML5 but I can't get a video to run in Firefox. It runs in Safari and Chrome. I have put up the .ogv, .webm, and .mp4 formats but still no luck.

It runs in Firefox on my computer but not on the GoDaddy server.

Here's the link: http://www.buildersclass.org/_img/2013/2013Feb/2013_Feb_chili.html

I have tried using Firefox on both Windows and Mac. Both give me the same error message: `No video with supported format and MIME type found`.

Here's the `.htaccess` file I use on the server:

```
AddType video/mp4  mp4 m4v    
AddType audio/mp4  m4a    
AddType video/ogg  ogv    
AddType audio/ogg  ogg oga    
AddType video/webm webm
```

Thoughts?

Comment: that link gives a 404 - did you ever get this working?

Comment: No, I didn't. Would like to hire a consultant to get it working but can't find one of those either.

Comment: Can you put the page back up and I will try and have a quick look

Comment: Thanks. It's now at:    http://www.buildersclass.org/_img/2013/2013_02/2013_Feb_chili_old

Comment: Looks like the video file is fine, I copied it to my server and added the MIME type and it plays back fine. For your .htaccess file have you got this: AddType video/webm .webm - (note the dot in front of webm)

Comment: I've got 2 htaccess files. One is ".htaccess." and the other is ".htaccess.txt"     The former has these lines:        AddType video/mp4  .mp4 .m4v    
AddType audio/mp4  .m4a    
AddType video/ogg  .ogv    
AddType audio/ogg  .ogg .oga    
AddType video/webm .webm

Comment: The second file ".htaccess.txt" has these lines:    AddType video/mp4  mp4 m4v
AddType audio/mp4  m4a    
AddType video/ogg  ogv    
AddType audio/ogg  ogg oga    
AddType video/webm webm     Don't know why there are 2 files there. Think I need to remove this one?

Comment: you should have a ".htaccess" no "." and no ".txt" after it, and it appears the format for you .htaccess is right ("AddType video/webm .webm" though make sure there is a carriage return at the end). Is it in the same directory as the video files?  ... I just tested on my OSX box with Apache and it behaves as expected

Comment: That did it! Don't know why I had a period there, just following someone's instructions from a long time ago, I guess. How can I repay you for your help?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow that's what we're here for - community helping each other :) it you just mark the Answer as correct all is good.

Comment: I'd love to do that but don't see any way to do that, my being a newbie and all. Where is the "Answer is correct" check box?

Comment: it's got a tick, looks like you got it - we work for ticks around here :) thanks good luck with the rest of the pocket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comment thread the answer was to remove a trailing period from .htaccess. so that the MIME type was being picked up